# Ivy artifactPattern with query string fails using Gradle

Tags: gradle, teamcity, ivy

We are using TeamCity for an Ivy repo and trying to access a resource in our Gradle build using a specific branch. The way to do this in TeamCity is to use the branch= query string parameter and so we have this in our build.gradle.

`http://xyz:8888/httpAuth/repository/download/[module]/[revision]/[classifier](.[ext])?branch=develop`

Using Postman this URL works just fine but when running Gradle is doesn't like the ? for the query string and tries to search this.

`Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://xyz:8888/httpAuth/repository/download/WpCommon_Build/lastSuccessful/dist/myjar-SNAPSHOT.jar%3Fbranch=develop]`

I've tried everything I could think of to make it work but no luck. Any ideas on how to get Gradle to use it? Maybe there's a way to format the TeamCity repo URL to use a branch without using a query parameter?

Comment: It seems like this is still broken: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/21297